# Do void* and char* have the same representation?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, void-pointers

Does the C standard guarantee that `void*` and `char*` have the same representation?
(Yes, I know that `int*` can be different of either.)

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Comment: Except that pointer-arithmetic on `void*` is undefined (though most compiler support it at treat it as `char*` arithmetic) because `void` has no size - weirdly in GCC you can set a flag so that `sizeof(void) == sizeof(char)`.

Comment: @Dai: There are plenty of differences between `void*` and `char*`. The question was only about their representations, which are the same.